# CAKEPHP - Change default path to webroot

Tags: php, cakephp, installation

I'm new to cakephp and I'm having some problems with setting up a local development server.  I have my cake install located at http://localhost/dropbox/my_site/.  However, when I try to visit that url, it tells me the dropbox controller isn't set up.  How do I tell CakePHP to start in `my_site` rather than `/localhost/`?

I've tried adding `connect(/localhost/dropbox/*)` to the routes, but it seems like it still looks for models in the wrong location.

I tried editing index.php in app/webroot but all the examples show how to write the directory in linux format rather than windows, so I'm not sure how to structure 'ROOT'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CakePHP will work happily in a subdirectory - I have several Cake sites running at http://localhost/{appname} on my dev machine.

Cake defines its ROOT directory in the root index.php file.  If you look inside you'll see the following lines:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);
```

Since it's taking ROOT from `dirname(__FILE__)`, it will always point to that file's location.

I suspect you have problems in your routing file.  Did you create any custom routing rules to account for being located in a subdirectory?  If you did, your cake install may be trying to access http://localhost/dropbox/my_site/dropbox/... and that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'index'));

That's the only thing I edited in my routes.

Comment: @Stewie and you get this error when you directly navigate to your site?  Or only after clicking a link on your site...?

Comment: When I go to http://localhost/dropbox/my_site it tells me dropbox controller doesn't exist.  The cakephp installation is in my_site folder.  -the second is case-sensitive

When I go to http://localhost/Dropbox/My_Site/ I get:
Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\My_Site\app\Controller\CarsController.php on line 10

Comment: Yep, that was it.
When I go to http://localhost/dropbox/my_site it tells me dropbox controller doesn't exist, but as it seems, the url is case sensitive.  When I go to http://localhost/Dropbox/My_Site/ I get another error, but that's just from some naming conventions.  I'm up and running.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This likely doesn't have so much to do with CakePHP as it does with your web server.

If *dropbox* is your document root, it should be mapped accordingly in your web server configuration. For example using `DocumentRoot` in Apache.

Comment: I don't have a separate site set up for this development site in my web server.  Maybe that's what I'm doing wrong.  I'm using wamp and I just placed my dropbox folder inside, with a folder for my application inside my dropbox folder.